# disable maven execution debug output

Tags: maven

Option -X in maven is able to display execution debug output including the parameters. is it possible to configure the maven POM.xml to disable the debug log output for the entire execution process or within the execution of one particular maven plugin even if "-X" option is passed in maven? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maven 3.1 has introduced SLF4j, which means you can have more control over your logging.
See http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html for all the details.
With earlier version of Maven the specified log level was for the complete execution.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. The POM will be executed in teamcity build agent. unfortunately, I won't be able to modify the local maven configuration in the build agent. I wonder if I can include some config into my POM file or invoke existing maven plugins to achieve the goal.

Comment: Then the answer is "no", that's not possible.

Comment: @user420985 actually you can upload your custom maven config file to your teamcity server: https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/maven.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<properties>
  <org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>info</org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>
</properties>
```

Comment: nu luck. Still the execution debug output was displayed into the console when option "-X" was passed in maven command line in teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`MAVEN_OPTS="-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=ERROR" mvn --batch-mode dependency:build-classpath
[no output]`

To crosscheck, with errors:

`MAVEN_OPTS="-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=ERROR" mvn --batch-mode invalid
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'build-classpat' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 among available goals analyze, analyze-dep-mgt, analyze-duplicate, analyze-only, analyze-report, build-classpath, copy, copy-dependencies, display-ancestors, get, go-offline, help, list, list-repositories, properties, purge-local-repository, resolve, resolve-plugins, sources, tree, unpack, unpack-dependencies -> [Help 1]`

Maybe you also want `--batch-mode` to disable colors and prompts.

You might set the level according to your needs.